# Front-end Image Upload to Custom Meta Box

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, front-end

I'm currently using a custom post type with a custom meta box for two image uploads.

I'm trying to create a front-end post page where the user can upload their own images from their desktop. All of the online examples worked - however they didn't submit to my custom meta box fields.

Answer (score 1):

When I was working on the same the issue was that when you try to add custom meta box before the post is created it did not work. So what I did was once the post was created added the following code

```
$imagepath = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $upload[1], $size );
update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_path', $imagepath[0];
```

So what happen's here is that $upload[1] is the image attachment id and using the wp_get_attachment_image_src i will get the source of the image url which you can attach to a custom post. Or you can use another function but this is pretty much. I am assuming you want a image path there are lot's of other function's you can use

Comment: I'm not very good with WordPress yet. I appreciate your reply, but I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: Hi Stephen
Can you show the code on what you are working it will be really helpful to explain..